# Parsing JSON from API to PostgreSQL Database using Python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, tensorflow

I'm fairly new to databases and APIs but would like to retrieve JSON data from an API and store in a PostgreSQL database using Python. Ultimately I want to store the information in a database so it can be used by a TensorFlow script.

I've had a look at previous questions on here but can't seem to find a solution that works. If anyone could provide any further information or point me in the right direction, that would be great.

So far I have:

- Created a table within my database on PostgreSQL
- Checked the connection to the database is ok
- Checked the JSON data is being read
- written the following code

```
import json, urllib.request, requests
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values


# Retrieve Json Data from Within API

url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

print(data)

# ***** connect to the db *******
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='postgres', user='postgres', password='********', host='localhost', port='5432')
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database")

# cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

fields = [
    'USD', 
    'GBP', 
    'base', 

]

for apidata in data:
    my_data = [apidata[field] for field in fields]
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO apidata VALUES (?, ?, ?)" #%d for int %s for string
    cur.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
    conn.commit()

# close the cursor
cur.close()

# close the connection
conn.close()
```

Comment: 1. What's the error message? 2. What s the typical format of the json returned by api 3. I don't think you dont need to make your row a tuple, you can explicitly pass each row of data as a list in execute

Comment: Hi @Willyzekid, thanks for your response. 
1. The error message returned is: 
C:\>python apisandbox.py
{'rates': {'USD': 1.095, 'GBP': 0.89535}, 'base': 'EUR', 'date': '2020-05-19'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apisandbox.py", line 81, in <module>
    my_data = [apidata[field] for field in fields]
  File "apisandbox.py", line 81, in <listcomp>
    my_data = [apidata[field] for field in fields]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

2. Please see above format of JSON file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apidata` (or `data`) is not you what expect - it's actually a string holding the keys of your dictionary. Thus the error... So what you probably wanted to do was simply

```
...
fields = [
    'USD', 
    'GBP', 
    'base', 
]
my_data = [data[field] for field in fields]
insert_query = "INSERT INTO apidata VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
cur.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
conn.commit()
...
```

But that won't work either because well the dictionary you get from the api is of the form {'rates': {'USD': 1.095, 'GBP': 0.89535}, 'base': 'EUR', 'date': '2020-05-19'} where 'USD' and 'GBP' are nested into 'rates' so you can't access it in a simple list comprehension. A quick and dirty ways to do it correctly below

```
...
fields = [
    'USD', 
    'GBP', 
]
my_data = [data['rates'][field] for field in fields]
my_data.append(data['base'])
insert_query = "INSERT INTO apidata VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
cur.execute(insert_query, my_data)
conn.commit()
...
```